# change Auto Layout dynamically

Tags: ios, iphone, xcode, storyboard, autolayout

I have to show 3 Labels like

**LABEL1 | LABEL2 | Label3**       `//Horizontally`

I want these 3labels width are **equally divided according to Screen size width**

How can I achieve this with nib file directly?

Thanks

**Question 2**

Label1 | Label2 | Lable3

//All Labels widths are equally

//All Labels are Subview of a view call X view

Label1 : height is 100

Label2 : height is 150

Label3 : height is 300

**Q: Now I want X view's height as max(100,150,300) = 300**

Comment: do you mean, adding constraints by code? or through storyboard?

Comment: @AshishKakkad, through storyboard

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Just give `top, left , right, height and equal width` constraints to all label....

[image]

[image]

Comment: Like your efforts (y) .

Comment: I also need one more help. if these 3 labels height are different & these are subview of a view then How can I set view's height dynamically to the max height of any Label's(subview) height ?

Comment: can you put screen shot of this

Comment: see my question2 above, let me know if you have any doubt

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/80557/discussion-between-bhavin-and-user2526811).

Comment: tx! I found in addition that if you want to be able to hide one of the buttons and have the other two divide the space equally, you need to add a couple of more lower priority constraints to the buttons that will be visible that will reflect what you want, and in the code you need to do removeFromSuperview, not just hide the button you don't want visible.