# What will be the constraint for equally spaced buttons in swift programming?

Tags: xcode, swift, autolayout, constraints, ios-autolayout

[When i run this in Xcode beta, only left most button is visible. Other buttons seems to be collapsed. Can somebody help me on this to fix the constrains for the 3 buttons, please?][1]

https://i.stack.imgur.com/UOGLO.png

Comment: You are using Swift? Add the tag then, to get experts in that area.

Comment: @bcsb1001 I understand you want to help, but do we know if OP's constraints are declared by code? Most people set the constraints in Xcode's Interface Builder, not by code. Here we don't know if it's the case, Swift might be entirely unrelated to this. :)

Comment: this might be helpful to you ... you can use buttons instead labels here  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30838475/change-auto-layout-dynamically/30838599#30838599

Answer (score 0):

For me, it works when I set the width for one of the buttons (in the screenshot below the one in the middle), for the other buttons the "equal widths"-constraint.

For the horizontal and vertical position I centered the button in the middle and set its space to the top to a fixed value. The buttons on the left and on the right are then centered vertically to the middle button. Like this:

https://i.stack.imgur.com/npFgM.png

Answer (score 0):

The current best practice for this kind of task is to use UIStackView if possible (iOS 9.0 and up).  You can just place all three buttons in a UIStackView on the storyboard (or in code), set its distribution property to "Equal Spacing" and just set constraints on the overall stack view itself to make it as wide as your overall scene, etc.

There's a good video overview from Apple here:

https://developer.apple.com/videos/play/wwdc2015/218/

Comment: Thanks for the video Daniel, I found it very helpful in many areas of my project.