# Arrange 3 UIButtons(of equal width) side-by-side

Tags: ios, xcode, uibutton, autolayout

How to arrange 3 UIButtons side-by-side.I am using Auto-layout.  My requirement is:

1.they should be equal width regardless of device

2.occupy vertically from starting to end of the view

[image]

i tried different ways, i failed to achieve that. Is it possible through interface builder

Comment: Try setting horizontal spacing 0 and equal width constraint. And set leading space of first to 0 and trailing space of last to 0

Comment: I didn't get the second point?

Comment: @kiran: i am new to ios .i didn't get you exactly.Can u explain in detail

Comment: @ujjwal : just i am saying the buttons should allign as i shown in image.

Comment: is your second requirement also got fulfilled?

Answer (score 23, accepted):

There are 2 ways to do this.

**Way 1:**

***With use of equal width constraint of button***

Select all 3 buttons and add

***top, left , right, height and equal width***

[image]

---

**Way 2:**
***With use of Stack view***

*Step 1:* Add 3 buttons.

*Step 2:* Select all that buttons, Once you selected, click on the ***Stack button*** in the Auto Layout toolbar at the bottom right of the storyboard canvas. see below in image.

[image]

*Alternatively you can embed in From* **Editor -> Embed in -> StackView**

*Step 3:*
Add **Constraints** to **StackView**. like below.
[image]

*Step 4:*
Select StackView, Once selected go to ***Attributes inspector***. Change the ***Distribution*** to ***Fill Equally***:

[image]

And its Done!

Comment: will this keep the buttons at the required position too? I mean what about the bottom margin?

Comment: You can give bottom margin as you want to set i.e based on requirement.

Comment: yes obviously, i just wanted to check solution for second requirement. anyways Thanks :)

Comment: @Ujjwal: yes ,i given leadng and trailing constraints

Comment: This doesn't work for small screens. The ButtonTitle will be shown as ...

Answer (score 6):

Select 3 buttons and give this constraints

```
  - leading
  - trailing
  - bottom
  - Height
  - equal width
```

You can check some references from [equal width to 3 labels](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30838475/change-auto-layout-dynamically/30838599#30838599) and from [setting two buttons of equal width, side by side](http://%20setting%20two%20buttons%20of%20equal%20width,%20side%20by%20side)

Answer (score 1):

Set the constraints as following :

1. Select all button and set the equal width constraint, this constraint will keep the width of all the buttons same.
2. Select all buttons and set the bottom margin, this will keep all the button at bottom of the screen in all form factors.
3. Set the left margin and right margin of first and last button respectively, with the superview.
4. Select the button in the middle and set left margin and right margin constraint.

Answer (score 1):

It is possible through interface builder. This is what you do

1. Create a UIViewController from your Storyboard by clicking the Object Library button. [image: See the blue circle with the square in it- that's the Object Library]
2. Now select and drag three buttons and add them to your View Controller. Be sure to add the buttons through here. Drag and drop in the View of your View Controller. Be sure to place the buttons at the bottom of your View Controller. [image]
3. After your three buttons are added , it should look something like this [image]
4. Now comes the interesting part. Now what you need to do is add constraints to your buttons so that they stay always at the bottom and of equal width. For simplicity let me call the three buttons as left , center and right button.  To keep the button at the button , select the center button  and press CONTROL on your keyboard and drag the button to the View. Select the constraint

> Vertical spacing to Bottom Layout Guide

and keep a constant = 0. Now for the other two buttons you do this. Simply press CONTROL and drag to the central button. Select the constraint

> Bottom

and keep constant for that constraint as 0.This ensures that all the buttons stay at the bottom.

Add the Height constraint as much as you want for all the three buttons.

At the end, these are the constraints you must have.

Center Button Constraint

[image: Center Button Constraint]

Left Button Constraint

[image: Left Button Constraint]

Right Button Constraint

[image: Right Button Constraint]

5. Now all you need to do is Control+drag the Width constraint of your center button to your ViewController.swift file and change the constant of the width to

   widthConstraint.constant = UIScreen.mainScreen().bounds.width/3

And that's it.