# how to give constraints for UIbuttons

Tags: ios, xcode, uibutton, constraints

how to give constraints for the buttons in the bottom as shown in image.

[image]

Comment: try this ... in this link there is 2 button .. you need to just work with 5 button with equal width constraint same as this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29620409/need-assistance-setting-two-buttons-of-equal-width-side-by-side-autolayout/29620794#29620794

Comment: why you are not using toolbar?

Comment: What is the toolbar? can you explain me in deep.@salmancs43

Comment: Easier to put them in a UIStackView with a horizontal axis and simply add constraints to the stack view.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

select all 5 UIButtons and give equal widths constraints. give following constraints forr all buttons:

1.Height constraint.

2.Leading Constraint.

2.Bottom Constrain.

4.Equal Width Constraint

5.Trailing Constraint(if necessary)
[image]

check here :[Arrange 3 UIButtons(of equal width) side-by-side](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36170982/arrange-3-uibuttonsof-equal-width-side-by-side)